# How to determine the line ending of a file

Tags: scripting, line-endings

I have a bunch (hundreds) of files that are supposed to have Unix line endings. I strongly suspect that some of them have Windows line endings, and I want to programmatically figure out which ones do.

I know I can just run

```
flip -u
```

or something similar in a script to convert everything, but I want to be able to identify those files that need changing first.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use grep

```
egrep -l $'\r'\$ *
```

Comment: for some reason, when I run this command in a MacOS X shell, I get a list of all files in the directory. Even one that I newly generate with "echo "test" >torderform6.cpp". Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: It just lists all files in the folder for me on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: This command will still list files that have had dos2unix run on them.

Comment: [Here's an explanation of what's happening with $'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script)

Comment: use `$(echo -e '\r')` If you can't have bash do ASCII expansion for you (replace `$'\r'\$` with it)

Comment: On mac I use:  grep -E -rl '\r' .

Answer (score 72):

You can use the [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(Unix)) tool, which will tell you the type of line ending.  Or, you could just use `dos2unix -U` which will convert everything to Unix line endings, regardless of what it started with.

Comment: file doesn't show line ending. Ex. : "file .bashrc => .bashrc: ASCII English text" Need some extra keys ?

Comment: @Fedir: Yes, it does, it's just that if the file has regular LF line endings, then it won't print any output.  But if the file has CRLF, bare CR, or mixed line endings, it will tell you that.

Comment: Didn't work for me on a CRLF-only Perl script on OS X. Might be a GNU extension?

Comment: This works on some file types but not others. On Linux, it doesn't report the line endings for html files for example.

Comment: "file foo.txt" worked fine on OS X 10.9. It printed "foo.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators"

Comment: Almost 10 years later, it's certainly worth mentioning that `dos2unix` features the `-i` option to get the information on the file. I have found this to be the most reliable way to identify the culprits. This is also described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/231408/17800

Answer (score 14):

Something along the lines of:

```
perl -p -e 's[\r\n][WIN\n]; s[(?<!WIN)\n][UNIX\n]; s[\r][MAC\n];' FILENAME
```

though some of that regexp may need refining and tidying up.

That'll output your file with WIN, MAC, or UNIX at the end of each line. Good if your file is somehow a dreadful mess (or a diff) and has mixed endings.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu, the accepted answer seems to just list all files

Comment: Doesn't work for me, gives: `Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?&lt;!WIN) <-- HERE \n/ at -e line 1.`

Comment: you need to replace the &lt; with `<`

Comment: The `<` symbol was messed up in a previous edit. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the most failsafe answer. Stimms answer doesn account for subdirectories and binary files

```
find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep "CRLF" | awk -F ':' '{ print $1 }'
```

- Use `file` to find file type. Those with CRLF have windows return characters. The output of `file` is delimited by a `:`, and the first field is the path of the file.

Comment: Indeed the most failsafe way. To convert only all found files just run `find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep "CRLF" | awk -F ':' '{ print $1 }' | xargs flip -ub` afterwards.

Comment: Most failsafe it is not -- `file` does not always even tell "CRLF" in its output, that depends on what kind of file it is. I have discovered that for SVG files -- containing text much like plaintext files -- `file` does not mention the kind of line ending used. This script thus is not file type agnostic. Just saying. Otherwise looks like a sane one-liner, aforementioned limitation non-withstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Unix uses one byte, 0x0A (LineFeed), while windows uses two bytes, 0x0D 0x0A (Carriage Return, Line feed).

If you never see a 0x0D, then it's very likely Unix.  If you see 0x0D 0x0A pairs then it's very likely MSDOS.

Answer (score 0):

Windows use char 13 & 10 for line ending, unix only one of them ( i don't rememeber which one ). So you can replace char 13 & 10 for char 13 or 10 ( the one, which use unix ).

Answer (score 0):

When you know which files has Windows line endings (`0x0D 0x0A` or `\r \n`), what you will do with that files? I supose, you will convert them into Unix line ends (`0x0A` or `\n`). You can convert file with Windows line endings into Unix line endings with `sed` utility, just use command:

```
$> sed -i 's/\r//' my_file_with_win_line_endings.txt
```

You can put it into script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function travers()
{
    for file in $(ls); do
        if [ -f "${file}" ]; then
            sed -i 's/\r//' "${file}"
        elif [ -d "${file}" ]; then
            cd "${file}"
            travers
            cd ..
        fi
    done
}

travers
```

If you run it from your root dir with files, at end you will be sure all files are with Unix line endings.