# How can I detect DOS line breaks in a file?

Tags: python, bash, file, line-breaks, line-endings

I have a bunch of files.  Some are Unix line endings, many are DOS.  I'd like to test each file to see if if is dos formatted, before I switch the line endings.

How would I do this?  Is there a flag I can test for? Something similar?

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121392/how-to-determine-the-line-ending-of-a-file (except this one's tagged 'python'  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could search the string for `\r\n`. That's DOS style line ending.

EDIT: Take a look at [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66434-change-line-endings/)

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go. There's no flag or anything.

Comment: Technically, you look for `"\r\x0A"`.  Most compilers use line feed for `'\n'`, but it's not required to have that particular value.

Answer (score 35):

Python can *automatically detect what newline convention is used in a file*, thanks to the "universal newline mode", and you can access Python's guess through the `newlines` attribute of file objects:

```
f = open('myfile.txt', newline=None)
# Python 2: f = open('myfile.txt', 'U')
f.readline()  # Reads a line
# The following now contains the newline ending of the first line:
# It can be "\r\n" (Windows), "\n" (Unix), "\r" (Mac OS pre-OS X).
# If no newline is found, it contains None.
print repr(f.newlines)
```

This gives the newline ending of the first line (Unix, DOS, etc.), if any.

As John M. pointed out, if by any chance you have a pathological file that uses more than one newline coding, `f.newlines` is a tuple with all the newline codings found so far, after reading many lines.

Reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

If you just want to convert a file, you can simply do:

```
with open('myfile.txt', newline=None) as infile:
    text = infile.read()  # Automatic ("Universal read") conversion of newlines to "\n"
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(text)  # Writes newlines for the platform running the program
```

Comment: -1  It's called `newlines` (plural) and it's not an encoding. What you have shown is how to find what (if anything) terminates the first line (if any). Your comment is incorrect: it doesn't include the case where the first line and only line is not terminated (and so `newlines` refers to `None`). Further, it assumes that all lines are terminated the same way. Concatenations of files of different line endings are not unknown. In the OP's application of standardising on one line ending, he will need to read ALL the input file (and ALL the docs, especially where it mentions `tuple`).

Comment: @John: Come on: -1 for an answer that mentions the useful `newlines`, but only with a typo?  Or for pathological files concatenated from files with different newline conventions?  The original poster mentioned "files from Unix or DOS", not such strange files!

Comment: @John: Your information about f.newlines returning a tuple in the case of a mixed newline convention is interesting.  I added it to the response.

Comment: I upvoted it.  I was a useful answer to me.  
@John makes a very good point though, concerning corner cases.

Comment: Thank you!  I did cite John's corner case in the answer, because I also found it interesting. :)

Comment: The file objects' `newlines` attribute comes from [io.TextIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.newlines) (Python 3): A string, a tuple of strings, or None, indicating the newlines translated so far. Depending on the implementation and the initial constructor flags, this may not be available.

Comment: Interestingly, the official reference given in the answer indicates that `newlines` is always available, though…

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated`.  I wonder which version started that?

Comment: Tried this with Python 3.11.6 and got the message: `ValueError: invalid mode: 'U'`

Comment: Python 3 now uses `newline=None` instead. I updated my 2010 answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

As a complete Python newbie & just for fun, I tried to find some minimalistic way of checking this for one file. This seems to work:

```
if "\r\n" in open("/path/file.txt","rb").read():
    print "DOS line endings found"
```

**Edit**: simplified as per John Machin's comment (no need to use regular expressions).

Comment: Shouldn't you open the file with "rb"?

Comment: Hmm, my first thought was no, because we're dealing with *text* files... But are you referring to this: "The default is to use text mode, which may convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading." (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)? I wasn't aware of such conversions – maybe "rb" should indeed be used for this to work on non-Unix systems too.

Comment: `re.search()` is not minimalist; it's OVERKILL; use `"\r\n" in open(...).read()`. There's no "maybe" about using `"rb"`; it's a must.

Answer (score 3):

(Python 2 *only*:) If you just want to read text files, either DOS or Unix-formatted, this works:

```
print open('myfile.txt', 'U').read()
```

That is, Python's "universal" file reader will automatically use all the different end of line markers, translating them to "\n".

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

(Thanks handle!)

Comment: Well, I'll want to edit them in vim.  I'd like to make that line ending change once and commit it, vs per file.

Comment: This will destructively change DOS CRLF to Unix LF on all files in the current directory:

  perl -p0i -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' *

I've typed this so many times my fingers have memorized it :)

Comment: @chiggsy install the dos2unix package, and run the dos2unix command on the files rather.

Comment: The `U` mode is obsolete in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function (which should work in Python 2 and Python 3) to get the newline representation used in an existing text file. All three possible kinds are recognized. The function reads the file only up to the first newline to decide. This is faster and less memory consuming when you have larger text files, but it does not detect mixed newline endings.

In Python 3, you can then pass the output of this function to the `newline` parameter of the `open` function when writing the file. This way you can alter the context of a text file without changing its newline representation.

```py
def get_newline(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            c = f.read(1)
            if not c or c == b'\n':
                break
            if c == b'\r':
                if f.read(1) == b'\n':
                    return '\r\n'
                return '\r'
    return '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

dos linebreaks are `\r\n`, unix only `\n`. So just search for `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep & bash:

```
grep -c -m 1 $'\r$' file

echo $'\r\n\r\n' | grep -c $'\r$'     # test

echo $'\r\n\r\n' | grep -c -m 1 $'\r$'
```